# PHP preg_match not showing results

Tags: php, curl, preg-match

I am trying to scrape this page to get the shipping cost for Standard delivery only. It is not showing results. I have tried different techniques for delimiting special characters. Perhaps there would be a better approach to single out the Standard Cost Price. Any suggestions would be helpful.thanks!

```
<?php
$curl = curl_init();
$url = 'http://www.amazon.com/gp/aag/details?ie=UTF8&asin=B009S7L8A2&isAmazonFulfilled=&isCBA=&marketplaceID=ATVPDKIKX0DER&orderID=&seller=A1N0I0RBOCG9TK&sshmPath=shipping-rates#/aag_shipping';

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; rv:1.7.3) Gecko/20041001 Firefox/0.10.1" );   
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

$resp = curl_exec($curl);

//echo $resp;


function amazon_scrape($html) {
preg_match(
        '/<td class="tiny" nowrap="nowrap" width="20%"><strong> Standard <\/strong> <\/td><td class="tiny" align="right"><table bgcolor="#F4F4F4" ><tr bgcolor="#F4F4F4"><td class="tiny" width="200" nowrap="nowrap">Continental US Street <\/td><td  class="tiny" width="200" nowrap="nowrap">\$(.*?)<\/td>/s',

        $html,
        $price
    );

    return $price;
}
$price2 = amazon_scrape($resp);
echo $price2[0];
curl_close($curl);

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can construct a class like below :

```
class amazon {
    function curl($url) {
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
        $data = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
        return $data;
    }
    function getContent() {
        $feed = "http://www.amazon.com/gp/aag/details?ie=UTF8&asin=B009S7L8A2&isAmazonFulfilled=&isCBA=&marketplaceID=ATVPDKIKX0DER&orderID=&seller=A1N0I0RBOCG9TK&sshmPath=shipping-rates#/aag_shipping";
        $content = $this->curl($feed);
        $content = strip_tags($content,'<TD>');
        preg_match_all('/<td  class="tiny" width="200" nowrap="nowrap">(?:[^>]*)<\/TD>/is',$content,$matches);

        print_r($matches[0]);
    }
}

$curl = new amazon;
$curl->getContent();
```

**Edit:**

You can change the `getContent()` function to :

```
    function getContent() {
        $feed = "http://www.amazon.com/gp/aag/details?ie=UTF8&asin=B009S7L8A2&isAmazonFulfilled=&isCBA=&marketplaceID=ATVPDKIKX0DER&orderID=&seller=A1N0I0RBOCG9TK&sshmPath=shipping-rates#/aag_shipping";
        $content = $this->curl($feed);
        $content = strip_tags($content,'<DIV>');
        preg_match_all('/<DIV id="fix_expanded">(?:[^>]*)<\/DIV>/is',$content,$matches);
        $rows = explode("\n", $matches[0][0]);
        foreach($rows as $key => $val) {
            if (!empty($val) && (!preg_match('/Total Shipping Cost for This Item/i',$val)) && (!preg_match('/Continental US Street/i',$val))){
                $current[$key] = strip_tags($val);
            }
        }
        return $current;
    }
```

And add another function to the class :

```
    function get() {
        $content = $this->getContent();
        if(is_array($content) and !empty($content)){
            echo "<pre>";
            print_r($content);
        }
    }
```

Than you can call it :

```
$curl = new amazon;
$curl->get();
```

I hope this will fit your needs.

Comment: This is good stuff. I got a response of an array...Array ( [0] => $75.00 [1] => $40.00 [2] => $0.00 [3] => $90.00 ). However, how would I just get the Standard td instead of all the td? Or is there a way to make more of an associative arrary that says Exp, 2nd, Standard, etc. ?

Comment: this actually returned the whole line starting with <td clas="tiny" instead of just the cost text. I just couldn't see it, it was hidden in the browser but can see it in the source.